# Matlab: ButtonDown event does not trigger if it is just after keyPress

Tags: matlab, mouseevent, keyboard-events

I have the following Matlab code (on R2019a). When I press a key it writes the key; when I click it write click, but if I press a key and less than 1s after, I click on the figure, the `MouseDown` event does not trigger. After 1 or 2s the trigger works well again.

Does someone have an idea of how to enable keypress and click without having to wait 2s between both, either by a trick or ideally by a clean method?

```
function testkeyclick()
    figure('WindowKeyPressFcn', @(src,evt) KeyPressed(evt),...
        'WindowButtonDownFcn',@(src,evt) MouseDown());
end
function MouseDown()
    disp('click')
end

function KeyPressed(evt)
    disp(evt.Key)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found, the bug was not on Matlab but on my touchpad which is automatically unactivated after a keypress.